# Add parameter to open crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Hi I'm new to crystal reports in web applications.  I'm calling a crystal report from my web application like this:

```
  private void AbreVisorReportesDict(int iIdRatificacion)
    {
        Response.Write(
            "<script type='text/javascript'>detailedresults=window.open('http://portalrpt/reportes/default.aspx?rep=SIDRJF/Dictamen.rpt&mod=116');</script>");
    }
```

But I don't know how to pass the iIdRatificacion in the url so that the report corresponds with that field.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a much better way to set the report viewer control's properties in your code behind
See:
http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/creating-crystal-reports-in-aspnet.html

ex from that article:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
        crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon
            ("amit", "password", @"AMIT\SQLEXPRESS", "TestDB");
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
    }
```

If you don't want to do it that way, you could just read the parameter off your own querystring and form the new string

```
string mod = Request.QueryString["mod"]
```

and use it in your output.